# How to add extra whitespace in PHP?

Tags: php, whitespace

I was wondering how can I add extra whitespace in php is it something like `\s` please help thanks.

Is there a tutorial that list these kind of things thanks.

Comment: We need more information about what you're trying to do. Do you want whitespace rendered on the web page?

Comment: Do you mean vertical or horizontal whitespace?  Space inside a string, or space between two elements on the rendered page?

Comment: this is not a php question, this is an html question because php outputs all spaces but web browsers ignore extra whitespaces

Comment: @Tobia: This is not necessary an HTML question. Maybe the OP ask for an explicit way to add whitespaces in a string other than the usual whitespace character. This can be useful in order to make them more visible. The linefeed character `\n` is a another example. Typing a simple newline character (by hitting the `Return` key) works, but using the linefeed escaped character is more explicit !

Answer (score 79):

Like this:

```
 str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5); // adds 5 spaces
```

Comment: `echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);` // add echo to print. just a reminder

Answer (score 24):

To render more than one whitespace on most web browsers use `&nbsp;` instead of normal white spaces.

```
echo "<p>Hello &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; punt"; // This will render as Hello   Punt (with 4 white spaces)
echo "<p> Hello       punt"; // This will render as Hello punt (with one space)
```

For showing data in raw format (with exact number of spaces and "enters") use HTML `<pre>` tag.

```
echo "<pre>Hello        punt</pre>"; //Will render exactly as written here (8 white spaces)
```

Or you can use some CSS to style current block, not to break text or strip spaces (I don't know, but this one)

Any way you do the output will be the same but the browser itself strips double white spaces and renders as one.

Answer (score 22):

PHP (typically) generates HTML output for a web-site.

When displaying HTML, the browser (typically) collapses all whitespace in text into a single space. Sometimes, between tags, it even collapses whitespace to nothing.

In order to persuade the browser to display whitespace, you need to include special tags like `&nbsp;` or `<br/>` in your HTML to add non-breaking whitespace or new lines, respectively.

Answer (score 14):

use this one. it will provide 60 spaces. that is your second parameter.

> ```
>  echo str_repeat("&nbsp;", 60);
> ```

Answer (score 12):

for adding space character you can use

```
<? 
echo "\x20\x20\x20"; 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) function. It is very easy to use. One example is below:

```
<?php

$input = "Alien";
echo str_pad($input, 10);                      // produces "Alien     "

?>
```

Comment: The example in this answer is incorrect - there should only be 5 spaces after the word 'Alien'.  The second argument to str_pad is the max number of characters, not the number of times the padding character will be repeated.

Comment: The question does not ask to put exact number space after any word :D :D
Sometimes you need to put extra space to fill up string length.

Comment: Sabbir, you are correct, but that is not my point.  In your example you state that echo str_pad($input, 10); will result in the following output:
    "Alien          "      (with 10 spaces)
But in fact it will output:
    "Alien     "          (with 5 spaces)
That was my only point, that the sample output is incorrect - that the "10" used in the function call specifies the total characters output (which will include the $input argument), and not the number of spaces to append after the $input.
I would have just directly edited the example to fix it, but SO does not allow such small edits.

Answer (score 6):

pre is your friend.

```
<pre> 
<?php // code goes here

?>
</pre>
```

Or you can "View Source" in your browser.  (Ctrl+U for most browser.)

Comment: I thought it was <a href="http://htmldog.com/ptg/archives/000077.php"> not advisable </a> to use pre ....

Comment: OP is a beginner.  He should just pre when learning and debugging PHP.

Answer (score 3):

#### source

```
<?php
echo "<p>hello\n";
echo "world</p>";

echo "\n\n";

echo "<p>\n\tindented\n</p>\n";

echo "
<div>
  easy formatting<br />
  across multiple lines!
</div>
";
?>
```

#### output

```
<p>hello
world</p> 

<p> 
    indented
</p>

<div> 
  easy formatting<br /> 
  across multiple lines!
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

is this for display purposes? if so you really should consider separating your display form your logic and use style sheets for formatting. being server side php should really allow providing and accepting data.  while you could surely use php to do what you are asking I am a very firm believer in keeping display and logic with as much separation as possible.
with styles you can do all of your typesetting.

give output class wrappers and style accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this

```
str_repeat("\x20", $numberOfRepeats);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `<pre>` tag to prevent multiple spaces and linebreaks from being collapsed into one. Or you could use `&nbsp;` for a typical space (non-breaking space) and `<br />` (or `<br>`) for line breaks.

But don't do `<br><br><br><br>` just use a `<p>` tag and adjust the margins with CSS.

```
<p style="margin-top: 20px;">Some copy...</p>
```

Although, you should define the styles globally, and not inline as I have done in this example.

When you are outputting strings from PHP you can use "\n" for a new line, and "\t" for a tab.

```
<?php echo "This is one line\nThis is another line"; ?>
```

Although, flags like \n or \t only work in double quotes (") not single wuotes (').

Answer (score 1):

to make your code look better when viewing source

```
$variable = 'foo';
echo "this is my php variable $variable \n";
echo "this is another php echo here $variable\n";
```

your code when view source will look like, with nice line returns thanks to \n

```
this is my php variable foo
this is another php echo here foo
```

Answer (score 0):

when you add more space between double quotes or single quotes PHP takes only one white space ,so if you want to add more white space between words or strings use tab '\t'  sequence

```
echo "\t";
```

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` is an easy language with multiple solutions. A Quick Solution would be using Double Quotes `" "`. Example Below.

```
$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "World";
$var3 = "How";
$var4 = "are";
$var5 = "you";
$var6 = "?";
$var7 = ",";

echo "$var1 $var2$var7 $var3 $var4 $var5$var6";

//Output: Hello World, How are you?
```