# Auto spacebar after a word with over 50 characters

Tags: php

Is there a function that can automatically add a spacerbar if a word is over a certain number of characters?  For example, given a word with 100 characters, it will post a spacebar at the 50th character.  I am creating a comment system, and if someone posts something like:

> ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF

it will mess up the look of my layout because there is no space in the word.

Comment: A word over 50 characters? I want an example :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300142/how-to-add-extra-whitespace-in-php

Comment: Why change the word itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div

Comment: Why dont you set fixed width to the comment container?

Comment: You can just use `word-break` in css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS instead of changing the actual word/string:

```
div{
    display:table;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k6puQ/)

Answer (score 1):

To answer with PHP, you can use a function like this one (if you really need to):

```
<?php
$str = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 ASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDFASDF';

function addSpace($str,$int){
 $output = '';
 $words = explode(' ', $str);
 foreach ($words as $word):
     $new = '';
     while(strlen($word)>$int){
     $new .= substr($word, 0, $int). ' ';
     $word = substr($word, $int);
     }
     $output .= "$new $word ";
 endforeach;
 return $output;
}
echo addSpace($str, 50);
?>
```

Comment: This will check the total post if someone posts something if you would do something like "Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum" it would still add spaces right? I only want it to happen to a word that is over 50 chars.