# How do i add tab space to php function

Tags: php

I am trying to add tab space to php function. i have try using multiple white spaces, '\t' but both are not working

this is my function

```
 public function getProductDescription()
  {
    return $this->name."\t". $this->carton_quantity .' * '. $this->weight.' g';
  }
```

Comment: You tried "&nbsp;" ?

Comment: Browser won't render the tab, do view source and you'll see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add extra whitespace in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300142/how-to-add-extra-whitespace-in-php)

Comment: Tab characters are treated as whitespace in HTML (assuming this is being outputted in a browser), unless wrapped in  `<pre></pre>`

Comment: php cli or cgi ?

Comment: Here's a thread with some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character/9661018

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a tab character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660987/how-to-get-a-tab-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `html_entity_decode()`

```php
public function getProductDescription()
{
    return html_entity_decode($this->name."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $this->carton_quantity .' * '. $this->weight.' g');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try the combination of

```
&nbsp;
```

For example,

```
public function getProductDescription()
{
    return html_entity_decode($this->name."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;". $this->carton_quantity .' * '. $this->weight.' g');
}
```

Comment: it displayed &nbsp in it's raw format, this is the output   " Cerelac Wheat&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;80 * 50 g "

Comment: Please do not add or re-add vote begging to your posts. I have downvoted on this occasion as a helpful reminder.

Comment: Are you sure about this? `&nbsp;` is not a tab char